# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from sessions where id = RlKtbVl23GJ84G2vXmLdwp7KGokTyBD6QM0HlaBN limit 1)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

when I was trying to set up my database config on the server using laravel framework I encountred this problem, I've deployed many website without any issues but this one didn't work,,

ps: in this project i used database driver for session.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from sessions where id = RlKtbVl23GJ84G2vXmLdwp7KGokTyBD6QM0HlaBN limit 1)

Comment: PS: my config file look like this :

DB_CONNECTION=mysql                                                               
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1                                                                                            DB_PORT=3306                                                                             
DB_DATABASE=####                                                                     
DB_USERNAME=root                                                                   
DB_PASSWORD=####

Comment: I think that id is missing ''.
Try with select * from sessions where id = 'RlKtbVl23GJ84G2vXmLdwp7KGokTyBD6QM0HlaBN' limit 1

Comment: even if i change session_driver from database to file, i stil got the same prb

Comment: The problem is the query. Try with "select 1=1" and see it that works.

Comment: i've never used this query in my project , laravel do that behind the scene  , so where i can find this query in my project ?

Comment: and why even if i change session driver i  still got this issue ?

Comment: Because IT IS NOT a session driver problem. Try make a query right into your DB, exactly like that and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried changing the ip address from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`?

Comment: This is not a query issue, and Laravel shows failed queries without the quotes. It uses parameterized statements, so this is fine. This is a connection issue with the database. Can you connect via the command line with the host, username, and password here? `mysql -h 127.0.01 -u username -p`

Comment: ok , the query is excuted fine but with no result , also select * from "sessions" means that sessions table must exist in db , and sessions table exsit when we use database driver for session

Comment: @WahyuKristianto yes , but same prb

Comment: @aynber yes i can